# Path Integral formulation with a spontaneously broken symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, vacuum, symmetry-breaking, ground-state

The path integral evaluates ground state correlation functions, and when a symmetry is spontaneously broken, there are many ground states.

Defining the path integral of a QFT in the naive way, I don't see any room for there being a degeneracy of the ground state.

How does one determine that a symmetry is spontaneously broken using the path integral formalism? And how do you account for the degeneracy once it's been determined that a symmetry is broken?

Comment: This problem arises generally with spontaneously broken symmetries. For example, if you look at the thermal states in the canonical ensemble you get a mixed state of all orientations of the order parameter, at zero temperature any superposition of ground states with different order parameters will again be a ground state. The common workaround is to introduce a term that explicitly breaks the symmetry and send its coupling coefficient towards zero, if the system has a spontaneously broken symmetry, the order parameter will not vanish when taking this limit.